# Is there a way to use Marko without the require hook extension?

Tags: marko

All of the markojs.com documentation says to render your marko templates like so:

```
require('marko/node-require')
require('./template.marko').render()
```

However, I couldn't find any ability to render marko templates that don't make use of a require hook.

I was hoping for something like this:

```
require('marko').compile('./template.marko').render()
// or the shorthand
require('marko').render('./template.marko')
```

What are my options here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just going to copy over my response from the [Marko Gitter](https://gitter.im/marko-js/marko) for greater visibility.

Your best options here are either:

1. Use `require('marko').load(filename)`
2. Pre compile your server side templates using webpack, rollup or parcel.